# Disable EnableOptimizations on Debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

Can you tell me how to handle 'BundleConfig.cs' file's below line when we are working on debug mode ?
Because I need to ignore below line on debug mode.How can I do that ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `#if` *Preprocessor* directive

```
#if DEBUG
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

If your app is running in *debug* mode, Visual Studio defines `DEBUG` for you. On the other hand, if your app is running in *release*, `DEBUG` will be undefined.

In order to check if it's a **release** version, you check for `DEBUG` to not be defined

```
 #if !DEBUG
     BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
 #endif
```

PS: For obvious reasons, there is no `RELEASE` flag.